# Sample from a matrix by rows

Tags: r, matrix, sample

I have the following matrix:

```
 Mat1 <- structure(c("Procedure_B", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_B", NA, 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_B", NA, 
"Procedure_B", NA, "Procedure_B", NA, NA, "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
NA, NA, "Procedure_C", NA, "Procedure_C", NA, "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_A", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", "Procedure_A", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", 
"Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_B", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", "Procedure_C", 
"Procedure_C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dim = c(53L, 5L))
```

I want to sample one value from each row, with the following constant probabilities:

```
P = c(0.99, 0.002992, 0.003186, 0.003018, 0.000804)
```

i.e. for each row sample each of its 5 values with these probabilities

The expected output is 53 values.

I tried:

```
sample(Mat1, size = nrow(Mat1), prob = rep(P, nrow(Mat1)), replace = T)
```

However outcome doesnt fit the expected distribution.
I dont want to do this in a loop/apply as my matrix can have many rows.

What is wrong with this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can sample column indices, and extract values from the matrix according to the sampled column numbers.
- This method is vectorized.

```r
set.seed(1)

cols <- sample(1:ncol(Mat1), size = nrow(Mat1), replace = TRUE, prob = P)
Mat1[cbind(1:nrow(Mat1), cols)]

#  [1] "Procedure_B" "Procedure_C" "Procedure_B" NA            "Procedure_B"
#  [6] "Procedure_A" "Procedure_C" "Procedure_B" NA            "Procedure_B"
# [11] NA            "Procedure_B" NA            NA            "Procedure_A"
# [16] "Procedure_A" "Procedure_C" "Procedure_B" "Procedure_A" "Procedure_B"
# [21] "Procedure_C" "Procedure_C" "Procedure_C" "Procedure_B" "Procedure_A"
# [26] "Procedure_A" NA            NA            "Procedure_C" NA           
# [31] "Procedure_C" NA            "Procedure_A" "Procedure_B" "Procedure_A"
# [36] "Procedure_A" "Procedure_A" "Procedure_B" "Procedure_A" "Procedure_B"
# [41] "Procedure_C" "Procedure_B" "Procedure_B" "Procedure_B" "Procedure_C"
# [46] "Procedure_C" "Procedure_A" NA            NA            NA           
# [51] NA            NA            NA
```

Answer (score 3):

You can utilise the `apply` function for this:

```
apply(Mat1, 1, sample, prob=c(0.5, 0.2412, 0.2397, 0.0191), size=1)
```

The `1` indicates that you want to use a function for each row, and then you have to specify the function you want to perform for each row. In your case, it is `sample`. After that, you have to specify the parameters for your sample function.

Comment: I want to avoid apply since this is loop-based and I have large matrices

Comment: Try to correct me, but don't you always have to iterate over the rows either way. So I see no speed issues here.

Comment: Yes you always have to iterate over the rows, but iterate  with `apply` or `for`-loop in R is slow. It's preferable to reconstruct the code to vectorized computation if possible.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the explanation, that is good to know!